# Error deploying using Azure cli to deploy webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy to Azure Web app. I've updated to the newest version of Azure Cli and this process used to work. I'm not sure what to do next.

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group $azure_resourcegroup --name $azure_webapp_name --src $package_filepath --timeout 3600


+     & az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group $azure_ ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: Gettin... zip deployment:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

WARNING: Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
ERROR: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\knack\knack\cli.py", line 206, in invoke
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 603, in execute
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 661, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 654, in _run_job
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\six\six.py", line 693, in reraise
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 631, in _run_job
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 305, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 485, in default_command_handler
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\appservice\custom.py", line 328, in enable_zip_deploy
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\appservice\custom.py", line 2332, in _check_zip_deployment_status
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo02umyl\requests\requests\models.py", line 889, in json
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being that the SCM was down. We scaled our apps up that that created new instances for us. I was able to deploy after that. Azure was showing service not available via KUDU

Comment: sounds very similar to https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11980#issuecomment-700589158. Check your resource usage is what I've learnt about this problem

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on this there are two types of error Validation error and Deployment error. Both types of errors appear in the [activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit). Validation error arise due to syntax errors in your template or trying to deploy resources that would exceed your subscription quotas but when operation passes validation, and fails during deployment, you may get a deployment error
To see deployment error codes and messages with Azure CLI, you may use below command:

```
az group deployment operation list --name exampledeployment -g examplegroup --query "[*].properties.statusMessage"
```

You may refer to below doc links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors#azure-cli

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deployment-source-config-zip